# Generating a Table in JavaScript with user input from a drop down list

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem, I need to generate a table using number of rows and columns that a user specifies (from a drop down list). I am having an issue figuring out how to get the table to work correctly when the user chooses the number of rows and columns they want. Help! I have a form and two select lists already created but I cant g

Comment: did you accidentally hit post too soon? because there's not enough information here to help you

Answer (score 0):

Building a table given row count and column count is quite simple

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < rowcount; i++){
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < columncount; j++){
        row.insertCell(j);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/BTCPd/)